# Spring MVC - should service return Optional or throw an exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have method `Optional<Product> findProduct(long productId)` in my `ProductDao` class.

- Should my service class (`ProductService`) propagate `Optional` and return `Optional<Product>`, then `Controller` checks if absent?
- Or maybe my service class should check if `Optional` is absent and throw an `ProductNotFoundException`?

I use `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` to handle `ProductNotFoundException` and return correct `View`. So my exception will be correctly handled in both solution.

Answer (score 0):

Optional is not really intended for the purpose of dealing with exceptions, it was intended to deal with potential nulls without breaking the flow of your program.

You can do something like this in your service class

```
optional.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("ProductNotFoundException"));
```

which basically means **return my optional value, but throw an exception if it is not available**

Comment: Nice shortcut for standard if-else on Optional. I didn't know this before. Returning to my question, if I understand correctly you suggest to throw en exception in the service class, not in the controller?